# Why is the setBackgroundResourceForDate being showed in red?

Tags: android-studio, calendar, caldroid

Actually I am using the caldroid library for android but in it I could not find any proper documentation for setBackgroundResourceForDate function. The files I have imported are:-

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment;
import com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidListener;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
```

and here the setBackgroundResourceForDate is being showed in red:-

```
if (caldroidFragment != null) {
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundResourceForDate(R.color.blue,
                    blueDate);
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundResourceForDate(R.color.green,
                    greenDate);
            caldroidFragment.setTextColorForDate(R.color.white, blueDate);
            caldroidFragment.setTextColorForDate(R.color.white, greenDate);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can see there is no method defined with the name '**setBackgroundResourceForDate**'in class :**import com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment;**
instead you could use ***setBackgroundDrawableForDate(Drawable drawable, Date date)***

You can implement it like this:

```
if (caldroidFragment != null) {
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(R.color.blue,
                    blueDate);
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(R.color.green,
                    greenDate);
            caldroidFragment.setTextColorForDate(R.color.white, blueDate);
            caldroidFragment.setTextColorForDate(R.color.white, greenDate);
        }
```

Comment: but i am getting an error ...its showing wrong first argument type!!

Comment: Ohh yes. First arg must be a Drawable type not a color id(int)

Comment: but how is it useful then ? I wanted it to be a color..can you pls tell me how you check if a method is defined in a class? how did you check it in my case?

Comment: You can use _`getResources().getDrawable(R.color.blue)`_ instead of using color resource id. You can check if a method is defined for your class from its documentation or you can just walkthrough the class code..